# Cant Find Symbol .DAYS Java

Tags: java, import

Apparently the .DAYS function is within the import java.util.* however for some reason this is still not compiling.

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.time.*;
    ...
    long daysBetween = DAYS.between(today, loanDate).getDays();
    ...
```

The error is cannot find symbol, pointing to the 'D' in DAYS.

Any help will be appriciated

Comment: Apparently? What makes you think that? Show us the javadoc for a DAYS class. There is no such class. BTW Classes are never, ever in ALL_CAPS. DAYS could be a constant, but then you would have to import it statically, or to import its class and refer it to its quelified name: `import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit; ... ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(...)`. The javadoc is your friend. Use it. Don't guess.

Comment: None of the Java class names are fully upper cased.

Comment: See this... https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#DAYS  `Days` not in `java.util.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;`
Import this instead.

Comment: I think he would still need to change his syntax to `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(...)`, but nice catch finding that enum :)